# How to enqueue some javascript source once per page

Tags: plugins, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I need my plugin to generate the following - once per page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://<ritc url for js file>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ritc.initialize('63864593a4153879');
</script>
```

The purpose of this is to allow one or more shortcodes - all requiring the same initialization - to be on a page. I can use wp_enqueue_script() in the shortcode function - this works for the first line 
ie.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://<ritc url for js file>"></script>
```

But how do I generate the next lines to follow - and only once on the page?
ie.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ritc.initialize('63864593a4153879'); (one line within script tags)
</script>
```

Is there anything like wp_enqueue_script() but which takes a string instead of a url? The string would be the one-liner above. Not to forget the dependency on the first line above.

Or should I just generate the javascript from the shortcode function, managing it so it only appears once in the page? (How do I do this? Is there a global variable I can use?)

Or is there another approach to doing this?

Thanks in anticipation.

Colin G

Comment: Is the number (63864593a4153879) always the same?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), it serves exactly the purpose you are mentioning: passing strings to Javascript from PHP. You can do all sorts of interesting things with that: as a rule of thumb, use that when you want PHP to communicate with Javascript.

In your case you want something like this:

```
$ritc = array( 'initialize' => '63864593a4153879' );
wp_localize_script( '{your_script_handle}', 'ritc', $ritc );
```

In this way you can call `ritc.initialize` in your Javascript.

Be aware that you must use `wp_localize_script` after you have **enqueued your script** and passing your script `$handle` as a parameter.